# Force git to update .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a `.gitignore` file, and it's ignoring some files. I have updated the `.gitignore` file (removed some filenames and added some filenames). This is not reflected in `git status`. How can I force git to update these changes, so that track files which are not tracked before and vice versa.

I have tried this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1139762/4576114), still all of my files are not tracked (according to my updated `.gitignore`). (In simple, how can I force git to retract files once `.gitignore` is updated or deleted).

Comment: Git ignore won't work on files which have already been tracked.  In this case, you need to `git rm` the files first before adding them to `.gitignore`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to add all files, delete all filenames from `.gitignore` file, not the `.gitignore` file and `commit` it, then try

`git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global`

Some files are ignored by the git depending on the OS (like .dll in windows). For more [information](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/).

Now

```
git add .

git status

git commit -m "your message"
```

**Or**

You can try a simple hack, it may or may not work. Delete all filenames from `.gitignore` file and add this line `!*.*`, then `add` and `commit`.

**UPDATE**

Simple, I'll explain with an example. Say you have a `build` folder which is already added and tracked by git. Now you decide not to track this folder.

1. Add this folder (`build`) to `.gitignore`
2. Delete `build` folder
3. Commit your changes

From now on git will not track `build` folder.

Comment: “delete all filenames from .gitignore file, not the .gitignore file and commit it” What does that mean?

Comment: if you are confused about this answer, see the answer from @Shravan40 : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38451183/1886357

Comment: @m93a please refer update section, follow the steps

Answer (score 293):

You will have to clear the existing git `cache` first.

**Remove the cache of all the files**

- `git rm -r --cached .`

**Remove the cache of specific file**

- `git rm -r --cached <file_name.ext>`

Once you clear the existing cache, add/stage file/files in the current directory and commit

- `git add .` // To add all the files
- `git add <file_name.ext>` // To add specific file
- `git commit -m "Suitable Message"`

As pointed out by Scott Biggs in comment that ***"This works for both adding a file that was once ignored as well as ignoring a file that was once tracked"***

Comment: I have explicitly mention (and linked) that this did not help my problem

Comment: Does `git status` track `.gitignore` file ?

Comment: To stop tracking a file that is currently tracked, use `git rm --cached`.

Comment: @Shravan after deleting `.gitignore` from local pc, no

Comment: Note that this works for both adding a file that was once ignored as well as ignoring a file that was once tracked.

Comment: `git rm -r --cached .` returns error "fatal: pathspec '–cached' did not match any files". git version 2.35.1.windows.2

Comment: What if I don't want to commit?

Answer (score 20):

It works

//First commit any outstanding code changes, and then, run this command:

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

//This removes any changed files from the index(staging area), then just run:

```
git add .
```

//Commit

```
git commit -m "Atualizando .gitignore para..."
```

Comment: this is already in the accepted answer

Comment: Indeed. Nothing new to see here.

Answer (score 7):

You can resolve this issue by deleting the cache of those specific files where you are getting this issue. 
The issue you mentioned occurs when you have committed some specific files once and then you are adding them in *.gitignore* later.

```
git rm -r --cached <your_file.extension>
git commit -am "Suitable Message"
```

Same solution is proposed by @sharvan40 above, but you don't need to remove the cache for all the files. It creates a new commit for all your files.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming here that your current working directory is empty.

You can check what files git is currently tracking by using `git ls-files`. If you have a lot of files, you can use `git ls-files | grep hello.txt` to find if git is tracking that specific file.

If it is tracking it, then use `git rm hello.txt` to untrack it (as Tim mentioned in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38450276/force-git-to-update-gitignore#comment64305497_38450276)). Perhaps commit that untracked state first and then add it in to your `.gitignore` on your next commit. I have seen some funky behavior in the past when trying to ignore and remove in the same commit.